# What's the number on Lucios HUD?

Tags: overwatch

There's a number on Lucios HUD right under the crosshair. It seems to fluctuate between 1-5.

Couple questions: What is the number? Can I influence the number changes directly? Is a higher number better?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The number lets you know how many of your teammates (other than yourself) are under the effect of your AoE heal/movement buff. For example, if the number is '5', the whole team is receiving your heals/boosts. If nobody (other than you) is receiving any buffs, the number disappears.

To answer your other two questions:

- Yes, you can influence the number by remaining in range and in line-of-sight of your teammates.
- Yes, a higher number is better. :)

Comment: Ah so '1' is just me?

Comment: '1' means 1 other player is getting your buffs. I've edited to clarify. :)

Comment: Thank you! This info will help me with my Lucio play now.

Comment: I believe the number also reflects how many would be protected by Lucio's Sound Barrier, so you can use that number to help guide your positioning when you're ready to deploy it, to protect the maximum number of teammates.